# Bxslider is not working

Tags: jquery, bxslider

**Bxslider is not working... What may be the problem?** I have used the same code that was in bxslider website...Please help me

```
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="./jquery.bxslider.css"></script>
<link href="./jquery.bxslider.js" rel="stylesheet">    
<script type="text/javascript">
  jQuery(document).ready(function(){
        jQuery('.slider1').bxSlider({
            slideWidth: 200,
            minSlides: 2,
            maxSlides: 3,
            slideMargin: 10
      });
  });    
</script>

<div class="slider1">
  <div class="slide"><img src="http://placehold.it/350x150&text=FooBar1"></div>
  <div class="slide"><img src="http://placehold.it/350x150&text=FooBar2"></div>
  <div class="slide"><img src="http://placehold.it/350x150&text=FooBar3"></div>
  <div class="slide"><img src="http://placehold.it/350x150&text=FooBar4"></div>
  <div class="slide"><img src="http://placehold.it/350x150&text=FooBar5"></div>
  <div class="slide"><img src="http://placehold.it/350x150&text=FooBar6"></div>
  <div class="slide"><img src="http://placehold.it/350x150&text=FooBar7"></div>
  <div class="slide"><img src="http://placehold.it/350x150&text=FooBar8"></div>
  <div class="slide"><img src="http://placehold.it/350x150&text=FooBar9"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: Any error in the console?

Comment: Where are bxSlider files placed? In the root or in a folder?

Comment: `<link href="./jquery.bxslider.js" rel="stylesheet"> ` <-- shouldn't that be in script tag?

Comment: i think you have the css and js misplaced

Answer (score 1):

The problem is this:

`<script src="./jquery.bxslider.css"></script>
<link href="./jquery.bxslider.js" rel="stylesheet">`

Should be:

`<link href="./jquery.bxslider.css" rel="stylesheet">
<script src="./jquery.bxslider.js"></script>`